# I'm trying to solve a problem at codewars using python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

So the problem I have is I think that the code is good, but it doesn't work as I would like it to.
Make a program that filters a list of strings and returns a list with only your friends name in it.

If a name has exactly 4 letters in it, you can be sure that it has to be a friend of yours! Otherwise, you can be sure he's not...

Ex: Input = ["Ryan", "Kieran", "Jason", "Yous"], Output = ["Ryan", "Yous"]

The code I wrote:

```
def friend(x):
    for x in friend:
        split_words = x.split( )
        word_count = len(split_words):
            if word_count = 4:
                print(x)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A tip: A string has also a length. And it seems that the task is to return a list - you print out all correct names. But you haven't told us what the actual problem is you want to address.

Comment: Hint: `= != ==`

Comment: There are multiple problems with your code, starting with syntax errors, type errors, and just plain wrong behavior. You should debug your code in a local IDE or even in a Python interactive shell if Codewars does not give you enough information.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the list of names.
Check each name's length: Using the helper function `is_friend`.
Collect the name if it is a friend in a list.
Print the resulting list.

```py
Input = ["Ryan", "Kieran", "Jason", "Yous"]

def is_friend(name):
    return len(name) == 4

friends = []
for name in Input:
    if is_friend(name):
        friends.append(name)

print(friends)
```

Or a shorter version using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
friends = [name for name in Input if len(name) == 4]
print(friends)
```

Comment: Please don't use list comprehensions for side effects. In fact, the expected output looks like you should print the filtered list itself, not the individual names.